# Spring Webflux : using flatmap + Mono for downloading google cloud storage Blob or just map?

Tags: spring-webflux, nonblocking, flatmap

I want to get a bunch of pictures in a google bucket and convert it to base64 using a webflux project.

```
 public Flux<String> getImages() {
final Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(PROJECT_ID).build().getService();

Page<Blob> blobs = storage.list(BUCKET_NAME);
long startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

return 
  Flux.fromIterable(blobs.iterateAll())
    .parallel()
    .runOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
    .map(blob -> blob.getContent(BlobSourceOption.generationMatch())) //blocking ? http request to google storage (returns byte[])
    .map(PhotoUtils::processBytesToBase64) //non blocking 
    .sequential()
    .doOnTerminate(() -> LOGGER.info("ELAPSED {}", System.currentTimeMillis() - startMillis));}
```

It works. I use Blockhound to check for blocking and nothing is detected. But I read several times that any IO operations (as blob.getContent() is) should be wrapped in a flatmap. So it would be something like :

```
...    
return 
      Flux.fromIterable(blobs.iterateAll())
        .parallel()
        .runOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
        .flatMap(blob -> Mono.just(blob.getContent(BlobSourceOption.generationMatch())))
        .map(PhotoUtils::processBytesToBase64)
        .sequential()
        .doOnTerminate(() -> LOGGER.info("ELAPSED {}", System.currentTimeMillis() - startMillis));}
```

But I feel it redundant.
Which one is the most correct or am I totally missing the point ?

Comment: I like the first. There is no need to wrap a `Mono.just` in a `flatmap`. it's redundant. Often I/O operations return a `Publisher` (Flux or Mono) and those need to be flatmapped. In this case the `StorageOptions` stuff is not reactive.

Comment: you probably wont even need parallel, parallel operations will usually only gain performance if you are doing cpu heavy calculations. IO operations is usually about orchestration, and not CPU power so you could even have worse performance since the operating system needs to send data and coordinate data over multiple cpus, which has a setup time.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I removed an image resizing mechanism for keeping code simple, it's why there is a parallelism.